# Calculating the inverse of $2^x/(2^x+1)$

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponential-function, inverse

I need help calculating the inverse of $$f(x)=\frac{2^x}{2^x+1}$$

I know this should be done using logarithms.

I started with $\log_2(x)=\log_2(\frac{2^y}{2^y+1})$ but don't know how to proceed.

Any tips on how to continue?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it the inverse function or the multiplicative inverse ?

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. Multiplicative inverse is trivial. It is just the reciprocal. I don't think he asks for a trivial result.

Comment: @edm Yes, trivial for us, but sometimes, a beginner can need help for a trivial result ... the aim is not to reassure the club, but to help, isn't it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y = \frac{2^x}{2^x+1}$$

Multiply for the denominator both sides:

$$y2^x + y = 2^x$$

Collect the $x$ terms:

$$2^x(y-1) = -y$$

Hence

$$2^x = -\frac{y}{y-1}$$

Taking the log base $2$ ($\lg$) we get

$$\lg 2^x = \lg\left(-\frac{y}{y-1}\right) = \lg(-y) - \lg(y-1)$$

Finally

$$x = \lg(-y) - \lg(y-1)$$

Comment: Perfect elaboration, thank you very much!

Comment: @Vicki You're welcome! :)

Comment: Your last step is not "legal" as $0<y<1$, so I suggest to finish like : $$\lg (2^x) = \lg\left(-\frac{y}{y-1}\right) = \lg\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)$$ then $$x = \lg(y) - \lg(1-y)$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: $y = \dfrac{2^x}{1+2^x}$, switch $x$ and $y$ in the equation,and solve for $y$. Can you continue?

Comment: I don't see how this hint will help. It is like "write down the first step and you should be able to do all the other steps".

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)-1=\frac{1}{2^x+1}$

$ 2^x=\frac{1}{f(x)-1}-1$

$ x = \log_2 (\frac{1}{f(x)-1}-1)$